# How to fix kvm owner and members?

Tags: android-emulator, kvm

I'm trying to start an emulator on vs code and i'm getting an error saying:
"Failed to launch Pixel 4 API 24: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds"

So i added my user to kvm , it didn't work. `sudo adduser <username> kvm`

Then i set the owner of the group as my user, the emulator launched but every time i close the emulator and launch it again i need to reset the owner for it to work. `sudo chown username -R /dev/kvm`

Is there any way to change the owner permanently or to make it work only as a member?

Comment: Hi @charbel, have you tried to change it in your bash profile so that you don't have to do that all the time you close and open the terminal?

Comment: I tries "nano /etc/group" and searched for kvm... my username was already added there @davide79